# Linq Error generating SelectListItems

Tags: linq-to-sql

This is a weird one that i can't figure out.

My method has one paramemer a nullable int

int? selectedtitleid

This is the Linq code:

```
var titles = from t in dc.Titles
            select new SelectListItem 
            { 
                Text = t.Title1, 
                Value = t.TitleID.ToString(), 
                Selected = (t.TitleID == selectedtitleid)
            };

return titles.ToList(); // Error gets thrown here
```

It works fine when selectedtitleid is not null - but throws an exception when it is null.

The exception is :
The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Boolean which is a non-nullable value type.

I did a test which was something like this

```
int? t1 = null;
bool b1 = (t1 == null);
```

And b1 gets set to false - so why doesn't this happen in the Linq query ?

It's probably something simple - so anyone any ideas ?

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, the `LINQ` query you provided will transfer to `SQL` syntax like:

```
SELECT 
    [t0].[Title1],
    [t0].[TitleID],
    (CASE 
        WHEN [t0].[TitleID] = @p1 THEN 1
        WHEN NOT ([t0].[TitleID] = @p1) THEN 0
        ELSE NULL
     END) AS [Value]
FROM [dbo].[Titles] AS [t0]
```

where `@p1` is actually your `selectedtitleid` variable.

Now imagine that `selectedtitleid = null`. This means nor the first condition, not the second in the `CASE` block won't be fulfilled. This is because null value in `SQL` (`null` is not equal to any other value even `null`). So when the `selectedtitleid` value is `null`, `null` value for the `[Value]` field will be returned. That is why you get your exception.

The workaround is to change your code:

```
var titles = from t in dc.Titles
            select new SelectListItem 
            { 
                Text = t.Title1, 
                Value = t.TitleID.ToString(), 
                Selected = ((t.TitleID ?? 0) == (selectedtitleid ?? 0))
            };
```

This means that insted of `null` there will be integers comparison. So if `t.TitleID` is `null` and `selectedtitleid` is `null`, `Selected` will be set to true.

Comment: Ahhh good man - that's perfect :)  
  
I actually tried doing (t.TitleID == selectedtitleid) ?? false - but because it's changing it to SQL it didn't work :)  
  
Cheers Alex

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this same issue when the selected value was a string, this is the exception because usually you would have some kind of an int or GUID as the selected value.  My workaround was to add a check for string.IsNullOrEmpty.

```
var x = from cp in db.CompanyPrefix
        orderby cp.CompanyPrefixName
        select new SelectListItem
                    {
                        Text = cp.CompanyPrefixName,
                        Value = cp.CompanyPrefixName,
                        Selected = (uti != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(uti.CompanyPrefix) && uti.CompanyPrefix == cp.CompanyPrefixName)
                    };
```